# Why does including the .h also make the .cpp source come along with it?

Tags: c++, compilation, linker

I'm an experienced programmer, but only in high level languages; I'm doing my first really large project in C++ right now.

I've got two classes, `ClassA` and `ClassB`; a `ClassA` is (among other things) an index of `ClassBs`, so `ClassA` needs to know what a `ClassB` is to build arrays out of it, and a `ClassB` needs to know what a `ClassA` is so it can update the index when something changes. Both of these classes are in their own .h & .cpp files.

I figured including each from the other would just cause infinite recursion, so I decided to instead have `#include "ClassA.cpp"` and `#include "ClassB.cpp"` at the beginning of `main.cpp`; but doing this just caused the compiler to warn about multiple definitions of every class and method in those files.

After some experimentation I found out that including `ClassA.h` and `ClassB.h` produces the desired behavior - but this doesn't make any sense, I'm only including the prototypes of those classes. Surely the code that actually makes them up never gets mixed in? And yet it does.

What's going on here that I don't understand? Why does including `ClassA.h` also make the actual code for `ClassA` show up with it? And why does including `ClassA.cpp` cause every include of `ClassA.h` to trigger "multiple definition" errors even though they're in a header shield or whatever it's called?

Comment: it makes the definition of the classes available. The actual implementation is resolved at linking time, from ClassA.o and ClassB.o

Comment: I don't quite understand your situation. Where did you include both `ClassA.h` and `ClassB.h`? In `main.cpp`? Also, what makes you think it makes the actual code show up?

Comment: In C++, an #include directive is only a copy-paste of the content of the file inside the current file. Usually you should only include .h file, instead of duplicating compiled code in a .cpp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The missing step is that the definitions in `ClassA.cpp` and `ClassB.cpp` will not be seen by the linker unless those files are *also* compiled at some point. If you did something like this:

```
g++ main.cpp ClassA.cpp ClassB.cpp
```

then all references to definitions in `ClassA.cpp` and `ClassB.cpp` from `main.cpp` would be resolved. However, if you only did

```
g++ main.cpp
```

then the linker would have no idea where to find the definitions in `ClassA.cpp` and `ClassB.cpp` and you would probably get an error.

If you're using an IDE, this detail is hidden from you: the IDE ensures that as long as you add a .cpp file to your "project", it will be compiled into the final binary when you build the project.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way how C++ is designed:

Your classes don't need to now anything more than the prototypes of other classes, so you don't have to include more than the headers.

Why is this so? Well, compilation of an entire application is the combination of two steps: compilation of the code itself and then linking (actually, there is a third step preceding these: pre-processing, but we could consider this one as part of code compilation).

Example function call: It is sufficient (exception: inline functions!) to know that a function with a specific proto type exists. The compiler then can generate all the code necessary to do the function call, except for the actuall address of the function - for which it leaves some kind of place holder.

The linker then combines all code generated during the compilation step to a single unit. As now knowing where every function is located, it can fill their actual addresses into the place holders, wherever they may appear.

Answer (score 1):

C++ code is compiled to `*.obj` for per `.cpp` file, and it is the `link` process make the obj files to an executable.

Never include *.cpp because it usually causes redifinition issue.

For each *.h file, add a macro to avoid multiple including:

```
#ifndef XXX_H
#define XXX_H

//your code goes here

#endif
```